# RMarkdown でPDF出力時に日本語が表示されない

Tags: r

RMarkdownの練習をしているのですが、PDFとして出力したとき
数式の中に日本語が表示されないという問題に直面して困っています。
どなたか解決方法をご教示いただけますでしょうか？

```
title: "授業：多変量解析入門"
author: "practice"
date: "2021/5/6"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: true
mainfont: Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro
```

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 8, fig.height = 5)
library(tidyverse)
library(socviz)
library(ggplot2)
library(gapminder)
library(tidyr)
library(lattice)
```

### 単回帰と重回帰

```
{r reading}
data <- read.csv("~/Documents/r_sample/R_Multivariate Analysis0726/第03章/顧客満足度データ.csv", fileEncoding = "CP932")
```

問題：数式を打つ方法はわかったけど、上手く日本語が表示されない。

単回帰モデル

$$
顧客数　= α+ β立地満足度+誤差
$$

Comment: お使いのOSやTeX環境, および出力時のエラーや警告がわからないと正確なことは言えませんが, YAML を以下のように変更してはどうでしょうか

```
---
title: "授業：多変量解析入門"
author: "practice"
date: "2021/5/6"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: true
documentclass: bxjsarticle
classoption:
  - xelatex
  - ja=standard
  - jafont=haranoaji
---
```

Comment: また, LaTeX の書き方を間違えています. 数式の中にテキストを含める場合は `\text{}` などで囲んでください

Answer (score 0):

ありがとうございます！M1チップのBig Sur 11.2.3です。Tex環境は回答になっているか分かりませんが、TextLiveの2021を入れました。

ご教示頂いた通りにすると以下のエラーが出ます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

普通にLaTeXの書き方を直したら表示され、問題解決しました！

LaTeX初心者なので、恥ずかしいです・・・。ご教示ありがとうございました！

Comment: エラーに関しては, コメント欄で改行やインデントが崩れてしまうので, 文字通りそのままコピペしただけだと失敗すると思います. 今回の場合は LaTeX 数式の書き方のミスが原因のようなので今のところはそのまま使用できると思います